# Как передать значение переменной из <script> html в функцию файла js, подключаемую этой строкой?

Tags: javascript, html5

В файле html внутри `<head>` внёс :

---

```
<script>(function (){document.write('\x3Cscript src="/sss/j01.js?id=' + Number(new Date) + '">\x3C/script>');g_file = 'sss';}())</script>
```

---

В подключаемом, таким образом, файле `j01.js` есть функция `myf`, которая работает с, объявленной в коде выше, переменной `g_file = 'sss'`.

---

Не получается уйти от этой переменной, например, запустив ф-цию `myf('sss')`, прямо из приведенного кода ... подскажите, плиз, как такое сделать.

---

Т.е. так не работает и через `if (document.write ...) myf('sss')` тоже :

---

```
<script>(function (){document.write('\x3Cscript src="/sss/j01.js?id=' + Number(new Date) + '">\x3C/script>');myf('sss');}())</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынеси вызов функции в следующий скрипт, чтобы он шёл после добавляемого:

```
<script>(function (){document.write('\x3Cscript src="/sss/j01.js?id=' + Number(new Date) + '">\x3C/script>\x3Cscript>myf(\'sss\')\x3Cscript>');}())</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Потому-что когда вы вызываете функцию mif, скрипт еще не загрузился.

```js
function getScript(url,cb){
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.onload = cb;
    s.onerror = err => console.error(err);
    s.setAttribute('src', url);
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
getScript("/sss/j01.js?id=" + Number(new Date), () => {
  myf('sss');
});
```

Comment: похоже на то, как правильно дождаться и вызвать из этого скрипта, не получилось ..

Comment: @Alex обновил ответ

Comment: С одной стороны правильно, но с другой, такая переделка может ему весь последующий код разломать))

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, именно с этим и борюсь .. беру Ваш вариант на вооружение. Спасибо.